# Rails FactoryGirl Sequences - Test created object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I use sequences like the following

```
 sequence (:role_id){|n| "10#{n}" }
```

Now when i create a factory with

```
 FactoryGirl.create :account, name: "name", phone:"1234", role_id: FactoryGirl.generate(:role_id)
```

How can i test for the generated `role_id` value?

```
 expect(account.role_id).to eq ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do it. Sequences are used to generate unique random data. 
If you want to have a `role` association on your model, consider something like this in your factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    role

    sequence(:email) { |n| "email-#{n}@example.com" }
    phone SecureRandom.uuid
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow how you use sequencing.

Traditional way is in your Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
     name { "whatever" } 
     sequence(:role_id){ |i| "10#{i}"}
     phone{ "5555" }
  end
end
```

You can then generate accounts like so:

```
account = FactoryGirl.create :account, name: "name", phone:"1234"
```

it will override every passed parameter with what you provided.

You can also specify `:role_id`:

```
account = FactoryGirl.create :account, name: "name", phone:"1234", :role_id => "1015"
```

Now, you can test any value you wish. For instance with RSpec:

```
account = FactoryGirl.create :account, name: "name", phone:"1234"
expect(account.role_id).to eq "1001".
```

But there is no point since what you are testing here is FactoryGirl. And that has already been tested. :)